# Using .bat - create a second .csv from specific first column data in first .csv

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a large .csv file and I need a batch process to create a new file with only certain lines that have unique identifier in the first column.

CSV looks like this.  Need to create a new .csv with only the 554,134,and 6852 records.

554,Apple,car,tommy
554,cherry,bike,tom
554,banna,skateboard,tomisina

844,Apple,car,tommy
844,cherry,bike,tom
844,banna,skateboard,tomisina

134,Apple,car,tommy
134,cherry,bike,tom
134,banna,skateboard,tomisina

6852,Apple,car,tommy
6852,cherry,bike,tom
6852,banna,skateboard,tomisina

78,Apple,car,tommy
78,cherry,bike,tom
78,banna,skateboard,tomisina

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out why this was never answered before?! The answer is quite simple:

```
findstr /b /c:"554," /c:"134," /c:"6852," "input.csv" >"output.csv"
```

If you have a long list of IDs to search, prepare a file with one search string per line like so:

```
554,
134,
6852,
```

Then change the command to use the search strings in the file:

```
findstr /b /g:"searchStrings.txt" "input.csv" >"output.csv"
```